# how to get div content by jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I developped a sample where I have a list in my view

```
@foreach (var pin in Model.myList)
{  
         <div>
            @Html.Hidden("idx", @pin.Id)
            <div><span>@pin.Content</span></div>
         </div>
}
```

and wrote html result is :

```
<div>
  <input id="idx" type="hidden" value="abc" name="idx">
  <div><span>123</span></div>
</div>

<div>
 <input id="idx" type="hidden" value="def" name="idx">
 <div><span>456</span></div>
</div>
```

how can I get hidden value in jquery when user click on each div ?

I tested this:
       `$('#pbid')[0].value` but this always return "abc" when I click on the second div

Comment: IDs must be unique on context page. To answer your question, inside click handler, use 'this' which refers element clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, ID:s need to be unique.

Also, you're targeting `$('#pbid')[0]`, which will result in the first element. Even though the markup is wrong. Change it from ID to class and don't hard code an element position.

Something like

```
$('.thediv').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).prev().val());
});
```

(assuming the divs that you want clickable gets the `thediv` class)

Comment: @motevallizadeh `$(this).find("#idx").val()`. But as I said earlier, I suggest that you change from ID to class since you're dealing with more than one element.

Comment: thanks for your help i will change my way and set unique id,but now i;m confused when each dive has it's id and user click on it how can i find witch div clicked by user?

Comment: @motevallizadeh By using the `this` pointer instead of hard coding a class. Look at my example :)